# What are the performance implications of NSString vs. NSMutableString for concatenation?

Tags: objective-c, performance, coding-style, nsstring

What are the performance implications of NSString vs. NSMutableString for concatenation?

In Java, concatenating two Strings may result in the compiler interning the two, making it more optimized.  If I am using a `initWithFormat` method of `NSString` to concatenate two literal strings, does any such optimization occur in Objective-C?

Also, is there a performance penalty I am paying by concatenating a variable with a literal using `NSString` instead of `NSMutableString`?

Here's an example:

```
if (![self.addressField.text hasPrefix:@"http"])
{
    NSString* newAddress = [[NSString alloc] 
       initWithFormat:@"http://%@", self.addressField.text];
    [self.addressField setText:newAddress];
    [newAddress release];
}
```

I would consider `NSMutableString` to be more analogous to the `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` classes in Java.  These classes are more appropriate for the concatenation of multiple or an indeterminate amount of strings.  If you know at compile time that you are concatenating *only* two strings, why not just concatenate them using the classes you are already using (`NSString`)?

Comment: Java string concatenation does not intern strings, AFAIK.

Comment: @Matt - Literal Strings are. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: I'm not trying to derail the question, but let's get this straight.  From [the Javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29): _"All literal strings and string-valued [constant expressions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/expressions.doc.html#5313) are interned."_ This has nothing to do with concatenation - it's all about compile-time constants.

Comment: @Matt - but if they are concatenated, then yes, they are.

Comment: how many strings are you concatenating? is this curiosity or are you actually having performance issues related to this? for just two strings the difference is not noticeable, and would almost definitely be premature optimisation.

Comment: @MCannon More than anything, curious.  The example above is the item in question.  A friend mentioned that `NSMutableString` would be the preferred approach, while I argue that for this scenario, `NSString` is perfectly fine.

Comment: In my particular test case (not exactly concatenation but similar) NSString is 3x slower than NSMutableString.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you want to find out which is more efficient, log a time stamp, and then call this 1000 times in a loop, then change it to an NSMutableString and do the same, you will see which is quicker. it is such a small difference in the scheme of things. but if you want you could reduce the number of lines of code:

```
if (![self.addressField.text hasPrefix:@"http"]){
    [self.addressField setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@",self.addressField.text]];
}
```